# incorrect password and receive an alert from program django

Tags: javascript, python, django

please im new to django and i want to add source code to my project, when the user try to connect, if the password equal to "test" i want that the template be showed again to the user with an alert javascript that says that the the password is incorrect
here is my code:
views.py

```
#Authentification
def home(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        admin1=AdministrateurForm(request.POST)
        if admin1.is_valid():
            nom=admin1.cleaned_data['login']
            pwd=admin1.cleaned_data['passe']
            for admin1 in Administrateur.objects.all():
                if admin1.login==nom and admin1.passe==pwd:
                    return redirect(menuPrincipal)
                else:
                    return redirect(home)
    else:
        admin1=AdministrateurForm()

    return render(request,'GPI/index.html',locals())
```

template:
index.html:

above of the code i put this one :

```
<body  id="page-top" class="index">
{% if pwd == "test" %}
<script type="text/javascript">alert("Mot de passe ou login incorrect !")</script>
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Where is your check for password equal to "test?

Comment: in the index.html: {% if pwd == "test" %} if the pawd is not "test" it will be redirect to menuPrincipal . is the pwd is "test" the program showed again the the same template with this alert

Comment: we can replace the string "test" by a password from the database but now i want just that this works

Comment: You should not use anything resembling this for authentication.  Django has [built-in infrastructure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) to deal with users and sessions.  Avail yourself of them.